# What is wrong with this php mysql code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

```
require("./connect.php");
$getid = $_GET['id'];
$getusername = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM user WHERE id='$getid'");
$getdesc = mysql_query("SELECT description FROM user WHERE id='$getid'");
echo "$getusername $getdesc";
```

I am having trouble, it is not echoing the data from those variables. I is returning resource id #10 and #11.

Comment: It is clear you are not experienced in PHP mysql database interactions. Stop using `mysql_*` statements and use something more secure like PDO or `mysqli_*`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch the data first before you can use the mysql_query result...

please see the example in the PHP Documentation
https://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,email FROM people WHERE id = '42'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // 42
echo $row[1]; // the email value
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:**

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the **MySQLi** or **PDO_MySQL** extension should be used.

pdo    : https://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

mysqli : http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.mysqli.php

> You are trying to print out the resource ID of the query you just ran.
>   To get to the actual results you have to specifically request it.

```
mysql_fetch_assoc($getusername); //should be used!
```